# Problema con switch de Angular-material, al recargar vuelve a su estado

Tags: angularjs

Hola tengo el siguiente `switch`

html:

```
<div class="inset switchdemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="Movilapp" style="float:left;" ng-cloak>
     <div>
         <b>Movil:</b>
         <md-switch ng-model="data.cb2" aria-label="hola0">
             <span ng-if="data.cb2" ng-cloak>Activado</span>
             <span ng-if="!data.cb2" ng-cloak>Desactivado</span>
         </md-switch>
     </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('Movilapp', function($scope, Conection, SaveCredentials) {

    $scope.data = {
        cb2: true
    };

    $scope.$watch("data.cb2", function handleFooChange( newValue, oldValue ) {
        if (newValue) {
            Conection.OnMovil({
                sucursal_id: SaveCredentials.getData().id_sucursal
            });
        } else {
            Conection.OffMovil({
                sucursal_id: SaveCredentials.getData().id_sucursal
            });
        }
    });
})
```

El problema:

El `switch` funciona bien, se consumen los datos correctamente, el problema es que si le doy click al switch y lo dejo en desactivado al reiniciar la página o volver abrir esta misma siempre volvera el switch a activado y no como yo lo deje y eso quiero lograr que si le doy desactivar se quede ahí y no haga cambios.

Entiendo que esto es porque yo a la variable `cb1` le di valor true pero pregunto

Como lo podría hacer?

Tengo otro web services que al abrir la pagina pregunta por el estado de la la acción. Si me devuelve 1 es porque esta activado, si me devuelve 0 es porque esta desactivado, podría hacer algo ahi?

```
Conection.CheckMovil({
      sucursal_id: SaveCredentials.getData().id_sucursal
}, function(response){
   if (parseInt(response.activo)===0) {

   }
})
```

Saludos. Aquí les dejo el enlace de mi código:

http://codepen.io/Hernan_/pen/NRyxyY

(no me lo acepto stackoverflow)

Comment: Amigo intenta agregar tu codigo en un fragmento de codigo que permite stack overflow para poder ejecutar tu codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa localStorage, o también [`ng-storage`](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) ya que estás usando AngularJS
    app.controller('Movilapp', function($scope, Conection, SaveCredentials, $localStorage) {

```
    $scope.data = {
        cb2: !!$localStorage.cb2; // Si ya lo guardaste se carga de nuevo
    };
```

La expresión `!!` te convertirá cualquier cosa a [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean), si `$localStorage.cb2` es `undefined` (en caso que nunca se haya ejecutado) se transformará a `false`.

Luego cuando manejas la llamada Ajax escribes

```
$scope.data.cb2 = !!response.activo;
$localStorage.cb2 = $scope.data.cb2; // El valor se almacenará
```

Cuando actualices la pagina el valor se restaurará del almacenamiento.